# a function with value between $0$ and $1$ and second derivative less than zero

Tags: calculus

How should I model $p$ such that as $p$ increases, $f(p)$ decreases and the value remains between $0$ and $1$?

so I have tried

$f(p)=\dfrac{\frac{p}{p_{\max}}}{\frac{p}{p_{\max}}+1}$
In this case as the $p$ increases the $f(p)$ also increases, where as the p increases the quantity should $f(p)$ should decrease.

$f(p)=\dfrac{\frac{p_{\max}-p}{p_{\max}}}{\frac{p_{\max}-p}{p_{\max}}+1}$
In this case as the $p$ increases the $f(p)$ decreases but the second derive is not less than zero. 
 while 
$p_{\max}$ is the maximum value of $p$ which is a constant. I have to use a function whose second derivative is less than zero, and the quantity remains between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: So what is the range of valid $p$?  (There are plenty of such functions defined on bounded ranges such as $[0,1]$ and none on $(-\infty,\infty)$.)

Comment: p has a range of $[0, p_{max}]$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(p) = 1-(p/p_\mathrm{max})^2$.

Answer (score 0):

The function $\cos\left(\frac{p}{p_{\max}} \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ works

Comment: Yes but the second derivative is not less than zero than

Comment: @user7341333 and now ?

Comment: The second derivative is zero but I am checking with values and it seem that as the $p$ increases the $f(p)$ also increases.

Comment: I forget the decreasing part. But now ?